# Change Tracking Delete vs Insert and Update

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I am working on a system which logs alle data manipulation actions centrally.
Currently SQL Server CHange Tracking is applied, but there is a problem in the data it tracks.
E.g. if I Insert a row in TableX, Update the same row and then Delete it, it seems like only the Delete action is being recorded. Does anyone know how to view the previous actions?

```
DECLARE 
@synchronization_version bigint,
@last_synchronization_version bigint;;

-- Obtain the current synchronization version. This will be used next time that changes are obtained.  
SET @synchronization_version = CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION();  
  
-- Obtain initial data set.  
SELECT T.* 
FROM TableX AS T; 

SELECT DTC.commit_time, CT.*, T.* 
FROM TableX AS T 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN CHANGETABLE(CHANGES TableX, @last_synchronization_version) AS CT ON T.fldId = CT.fldId 
JOIN sys.dm_tran_commit_table DTC ON CT.sys_change_version = DTC.commit_ts;
```

Comment: Are you sure the changes are not too old that they were removed automatically? Are you sure the changes happened since `@last_synchronization_version`

Comment: From the [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server) page... _If an application requires information about all the changes that were made and the intermediate values of the changed data, using [change data capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server), instead of change tracking, might be appropriate._

Comment: @Charlieface I tested it by inserting data and running the query. It then returns the inserted row. After updating the same row the query returns the same row still being the Insert-action. Next I delete the row and the query only return that row being deleted. Does it have something to do with the synchronization version?

Comment: [From the docs:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/changetable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#changetablechanges) "Only one row is returned for each row in the user table that has been changed, even if there have been multiple changes to the same row since the last_sync_version value." so it looks like @AlwaysLearning is right, this is not possible with Change Tracking. Possibly you could query `syscommittab` yourself and get the data, I believe every change should be there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @AlwaysLearning the solution was to use Change Data Capture (CDC) ([Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server)) instead of Change Tracking (CT).